# Where should the CSS transition property go?

Tags: css, css-transitions

When creating a CSS Transition for an element, should the `transition` property be applied to the element's existing class (or id or selector) or to the new class that causes the transition? It works either way I believe, but is one way better than the other and why?

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/15nj8y70/)

```css
.box {
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    background: blue;
}

/* background-change class to be added to the element with the box class */
.background-change {
    background: red;
    /* Should this be under .background-change or .box? */
    transition: background 2s;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use both of these variants, they're both OK. But you should understand the difference between them.

If you set `transition` property to new/separate class, your transition will be applied only when you set this class:

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sergdenisov/s5Lsuqee/)

```js
$('.box').hover(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('background-change');
});
```

```css
.box {
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    background: green;
}

.background-change {
    background: red;
    transition: background 2s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="box">Hover it to change background</div>
```

But if you set `transition` property to main/existing class, your transition will be applied also when you remove class:

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sergdenisov/c0kmyxx6/)

```js
$('.box').hover(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('background-change');
});
```

```css
.box {
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    background: green;
    transition: background 2s;
}

.background-change {
    background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="box">Hover it to change background</div>
```

I prefer to use the last variant because it looks better and consistently.

Answer (score 0):

It should be applied to the original class. The final result (in this case the background value) should be applied in the new class.

The transition property does not initialize the transition, it just tells the element that any difference will have that transition.

I recommend this article for more in depth reading: http://alistapart.com/article/understanding-css3-transitions

Answer (score 0):

This is how it should be:

```
.box {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background: blue;
  transition: background 2s; 
}

.background-change {
  background: red;     
}
```